# Elegant way to set alphabet variable like Excel columns

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a nice way to have a variable `alpha` that would increment as follow: when `x=0 -> alpha = "A"`; `x=1 -> alpha = "B"`; ... `x=25 -> alpha = "Z"`; `x=26 -> alpha = "AA"`; `x=27 -> alpha = "AB"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

OK sorry I just didn't understand your need at first. Here is a working code.

Try this:

```js
var x = 807;
var alpha = '';
var alphabetLength = 26;


var y = x.toString(alphabetLength);
chars = y.split('');
for (var i=0; i < chars.length; i++ ) {
 var charFactor = 65;
 var curChar = chars[i];
 if (isNaN(curChar)) {
 
  alpha += String.fromCharCode(curChar.toUpperCase().charCodeAt() + 10);
 } else {
  if ( i < chars.length-1) {
   charFactor--;
  }
  alpha += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(curChar) + charFactor);
 }
}

console.log(alpha)
```

Comment: Thought this was good but it doesn't work... after "AZ" you get "AAA" instead of "AB"

Comment: @ncohen Please, try now. I misunderstood your question at first

Answer (score 5):

You could use `toString` with base `36` for converting to the wanted letters.

```js
function convert(n) {
    var result = '';
    do {
        result = (n % 26 + 10).toString(36) + result;
        n = Math.floor(n / 26) - 1;
    } while (n >= 0)
    return result.toUpperCase();
}

//           A  B   Z  AA  AB   CZ   DXH
console.log([0, 1, 25, 26, 27, 103, 3335].map(convert));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) method and generate string using char code.

```
// initialize as empty string
var alpha = '';
// iterate upto value is reaching -1 since index starts from 0
while (x > -1) {
  // get charactor by finding remainder 
  // and concatenate it with alpha
  alpha = String.fromCharCode(65 + x % 26) + alpha;
  // update value of variable x 
  // decrement by 1 since index starts from 0
  x = Math.floor(x / 26) - 1;
}
```

```js
[1, 28, 25, 26, 27, 3335, 12, 10, 3, 6, 0].forEach(function(x) {
  var alpha = '';
  while (x > -1) {
    alpha = String.fromCharCode(65 + x % 26) + alpha;
    x = Math.floor(x / 26) - 1;
  }
  console.log(alpha);
});
```

Comment: @Null Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a one liner for this:

```
(alpha).toString(26).split('').map((b26) => (parseInt(b26,26) + 10).toString(36)).join('').toUpperCase()
```

The basic idea is to convert your number into base 26, which means 0-9a-p, and then add 10 so that the output range is a-z.

Here's a quick test showing that it works for the first 100 numbers.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  console.log(i, (i).toString(26).split('').map((b26) => (parseInt(b26,26) + 10).toString(36)).join('').toUpperCase())    
}
```